# Prawn - Links inside table cells

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn

I am trying to generate PDFs with Prawn.  Inside my PDF template I have tables with cells.  In one of those cells I have an email address:

```
cell_email = pdf.make_cell(:content => booking.user_email, :border_width => 0)
```

I want to make email to link to "mailto" link.  I know I can link some way like this:

```
pdf.formatted_text([{:text => booking.user_email, :link => "mailto: #{booking.user_email}"}])
```

However combining those two lines (giving formatted text as a content) doesn't work:

```
cell_email = pdf.make_cell(:content => pdf.formatted_text([{:text => booking.user_email, :link => "mailto: #{booking.user_email}"}]), :border_width => 0)
```

Any ideas how can I overcome this issue (create an email link inside the table cell)?

Kind Regards and Many Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can specify `inline_format` for the cell and create the link yourself:

```
cell_email = pdf.make_cell(
  :content => "<link href='mailto:#{booking.user_email}'>#{booking.user_email}</link>",
  :inline_format => true
)
```

You can specify `inline_format` for the whole table, too:

```
table data, :cell_style => { :inline_format => true }
```

Prawn's `inline_format` supports `<b>`, `<i>`, `<u>`, `<strikethrough>`, `<sub>`, `<sup>`, `<font>`, `<color>` and `<link>`.

Comment: Great, thanks! The only caveat I have is, if you have nested tables, you'll need to add the inline format in an initializer block, like so: `table(data) do; cells.each { |c| c.inline_format = true if c.respond_to?(:inline_format) }; end`

Answer (score 2):

The following underlines the link and gives it a blue colour:

```
link = make_cell(content: "<color rgb='0000FF'> <u> <link href='https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390505/prawn-links-inside-table-cells'> #{booking.user_email} </link></u> </color>", inline_format: true)

data = [[link]]

table(data,:header => true, :row_colors =>["F0F0F0","FFFFCC"]) do      
end
```